# css: Use two classes for one icon

Tags: css, icons

I have an icon that I call it like this:

```
<i class="fa icon-potencial_biomasa "></i>
```

But I have 2 classes on css associated to this icon:

```
.icon-potencial_biomasa .path1:before {
  content: "\e979";
  color: rgb(62, 164, 192);
}
.icon-potencial_biomasa .path2:before {
  content: "\e97a";
  margin-left: -1em;
  color: rgb(64, 164, 192);
}
```

But It has to be only 1 icon. That css is not mine, I have to use it to set the icon `icon-potencial_biomasa`. How can I do it? not sure how to setp up the code in the css. I don't understand what is doing the `.path1:before` and path2.

What I need to do is this:

[image]

I need to the the icon of the bottom, don't know how to.

Comment: Those are unicode characters. [A question mark](https://www.utf8icons.com/character/59770/UTF-8-character) should appear in that place, although some fonts will display different characters.

Comment: The icons are being added via pseudo elements with the `content` attribute pointing to the Unicode code for the icon. You can't have two `:before` pseudo elements. In order to stack the icons you'll have to combine both icons into a single icon in your icon font.

Comment: Something like content: \ecode1\ecode2  <--? like that way? How can add margin to one of those

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't. If you you were able to inject HTML into `content` then you could. But if you could, why wouldn't you just do that in the markup to begin with. As far as I can see you have two solutions available, **1** combine the icons in the font icon or **2** use more involved markup (more than one element).

Comment: @pmirnd a solution for **#2** in my last comment might look something like [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j81Lryyu/).

Comment: I can't change the html, I only can change the css code. I have to use 1 class only